# SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier in IE10

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, internet-explorer-10

In my project I am using the Prototype JavaScript Framework 1.7.1

When I load the web page in IE10 on Windows 7 I get the error message below:
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier line 1 character 9 which points to `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my test HTML page below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My webpage title</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    just testing
</body>
</html>
```

HTTP Request Header

```
GET /test.html HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: www.mydomain.com[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.44 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8[CRLF]
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
```

HTTP Response Header

```
Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: webhost 
Date:   Tue, 26 Mar 2013 10:07:56 GMT   
Content-Type:   text/html   
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked 
Connection: close   
Vary:   Accept-Encoding,User-Agent  
Last-Modified:  Tue, 26 Mar 2013 10:07:29 GMT   
Cache-Control:  max-age=3600, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate 
Expires:    Tue, 26 Mar 2013 11:07:56 GMT   
Pragma: public  
CF-RAY: 553096521a6047f 
Content-Encoding:   gzip
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error or is this a bug in Prototype 1.7.1?

Comment: Do you have a HTML doctype at the top of your JavaScript file??? Or does the error point to your html document?

Comment: Thanks for the markup. Could you show us the headers your server is sending for this document (or link to your server)?

Comment: Strange. And the error doesn't happen if you remove the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Yes If I remove the script tag the error does not occur

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>See this pull request on Github https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/pull/93</strike>

PrototypeJS does some feature detection everytime it loads and Internet Explorer 10 has adjusted the way some of the Javascript syntax is parsed and throws that error.

PrototypeJS is doing a detection to see how to handle passing functions as tag attributes (like an onclick method) and the IE10 javascript parser detects that as a syntax error.

If you look at the pull request in Github it will show you a band-aid as well as a full fix to make Internet Explorer 10 happy.

Please spread the word.

<strike>**2013-05-17 UPDATE** The pull request referenced has been closed and a fix has been integrated into the the master branch of the PrototypeJS github</strike>

https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype

Please clone from there and update your scripts.

**2014-05-01 UPDATE** The fix for this has been released in PrototypeJS 1.7.2

http://prototypejs.org/2014/04/18/prototype-1-7-2/

Comment: So it's again odd line number references in IE error messages?

Comment: The line number reference doesn't refer to the correct place in the javascript, its weird I know. I did extensive digging to find the javascript call that was causing this and was able to narrow it down to the attribute feature test in the code. The commits to the github pull request are the changes that fix this problem.

Comment: @bonez are you sure its the SCRIPT1010 error. We specifically searched for this error, tested it and resolved it. I'm getting my test VM up and running to make sure.

Comment: sorry my mistake. wordpress was loading old script version from google and not picking up my local file. problem fixed.