# IE11 Angular 2 error "Expected identifier, string or number"

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, internet-explorer-11, angular-cli

Well, I have created site using Angular 2. When I run "ng-serve" command and trying to test my site using "http://localhost:4200" in Google Chrome and IE11 it works perfectly, but, if I build project using "ng-build --prod", host it on IIS. Site still works on Chrome, but IE11 shows the following errors: 
[image: Expected identifier, string or number]

I googled it and found that it was maybe reserved words in my identifiers key:value pairs. So I added Apostrophes(') arround my keys.
For example I had the following object:

```
user:UserViewModel={
    Username:"",
    Age:0
};
and changed this to:
user:UserViewModel={
    'Username':"",
    'Age':0
};
```

Also deleted last commas in key:value pairs and imported core.js in polyfills.ts

Comment: Exactly same problem for me. No solve found any where.

Comment: What's the code at the positions mentioned in the error output?

Comment: This might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675622/script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632568/script1010-expected-identifier-in-ie10

Comment: can you show us your polyfills.ts file?

Comment: also, what version of the cli are you using?

Answer (score 23):

The main problem is IE has Compatibility Mode enabled by default. And IE 11 has some compatibility mode issues.
As per the followings question answer [Angular 2 / 4 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-not-working-in-ie11)

When I tried to **disable the compatibility mode off It works fine**.

But ingeneral user will not off the compatibility mode. So I want a good solution for that.

Then I found following solution form [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags)

```
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: bless your soul

Answer (score -3):

> I googled it and found that it was maybe reserved words in my identifiers key:value pairs.

No. These are not relevant to IE11.

## Fix

You are most likely running raw `.ts` files. You should be hosting (in your script tags) the bundled / built `.js` files.