# Angular6 + IE11 issue - Running dist folder on external server isnt working

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6

I need some help. I have successfully run Angular6 on IE in a development environment by modifying the polyfills and installing those necessary to run it. My problem is when I build the --prod 'dist' folder and move it to a server, it doesn't work. I get the title and favicon in the tab but nothing renders in the browser, which is the exact problem I had before modifying the polyfills in dev. Seems like something is not working when I build the dist folder. I'm wondering why this is! If anyone has info please help.

Comment: Please provide any JS errors or other errors (e.g. network 404s, etc) that are occurring in your browser.

Comment: Hi Daniel, when I run it externally in IE I get a "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" error 4 times with each .js file trailing the error...

browser-sync-client.js, runtime.js, polyfills.js, and main.js

Comment: Did you look at this question/answer already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086130/ie11-angular-2-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number

Comment: That works! It was the compatibility mode issue.