# YouTube API failing on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube-api

I've been playing around with YouTube API to display playlist on a side bar as explained in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459015/how-to-embed-a-youtube-playlist-with-a-sidebar). I have given the full code as well in the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/skyrocker/pen/jONrvwO).

However, IE failing to display the playlist. the below is the console error.

[image: IE Console Error]

This the line it triggers the error

```
function getPlaylistItems(pageToken) {
        return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            "part": "snippet,contentDetails",
            "maxResults": 50,
            "playlistId": PLAYLIST_ID, 
            pageToken //Error is in this line
        }).then(function(response) {
        const {items, nextPageToken} = response.result;


        playlistItems.push(...items);

        var index = 0;
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            const thumbnailItem = createPlaylistItem(item, index);
            playlist.appendChild(thumbnailItem);
            index++;
        });
        maxVideoVisible = index - 3;

        if (nextPageToken) {
            getPlaylistItems(nextPageToken);
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.error("Execute error", err);
    });
}
```

Can someone help me to understand this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of IE do you use ... Because i'm not a professional but Object destructuration is not supported (i think) as well as Promises... But maybe i am wrong I just try to help

Comment: `pageToken` key does not have a value

Comment: This error triggers only on IE 11. works on every other browser including Microsoft Edge

Comment: @ThumChoonTat it doesn't need to have value. I added the full function to the question

Comment: you need to apply your nextPageToken to pageToken: nextPageToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fount the issue. The problem is that the Internet Explorer does not support [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I found the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485236/ie11-throw-expected-identifier-script1010-on-vendor-js-in-webpack-var-injection)

So instead of below line,

```
const {items, nextPageToken} = response.result;
```

we should rewrite the section as below,

```
const hash = response.result;
items = hash.items,
nextPageToken = hash.nextPageToken;
```

and also the below line,

```
pageToken
```

should be written as,

```
"pageToken" : pageToken
```

The below is the final fixed code. Whoever facing the same issues can use the below code.

```
    function getPlaylistItems(pageToken) {
        return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            "part": "snippet,contentDetails",
            "maxResults": 50, // This is the maximum available value, according to the Google docs
            "playlistId": PLAYLIST_ID, 
            "pageToken" : pageToken
        }).then(function(response) {

            //Fixed code
            const hash = response.result;
            items = hash.items,
            nextPageToken = hash.nextPageToken;

            // The items[] is an array of a playlist items.
            // nextPageToken - if empty - there are no items left to fetch
            playlistItems.push(items);

            // It's up to you, how to handle the item from playlist. 
            // Add 'onclick' events to navigate to another video, or use another thumbnail image quality 
            var index = 0;
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                const thumbnailItem = createPlaylistItem(item, index);
                playlist.appendChild(thumbnailItem);
                index++;
            });
            maxVideoVisible = index - 3;

            // Recursively get another portion of items, if there any left
            if (nextPageToken) {
                getPlaylistItems(nextPageToken);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.error("Execute error", err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something like this.

```
gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            "part": "snippet,contentDetails",
            "maxResults": 50,
            "playlistId": PLAYLIST_ID, 
            pageToken : NextPageToken 
        }).then(function (response) {
              // if response.result.nextPageToken exists, use it
              if (response.result.nextPageToken) {
                 NextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;                        
              } else {
                 NextPageToken = false;
              }
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the [YouTube PlaylistItems: list document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), the pageToken is a string type, so, the code as below:

```
    return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
        "part": "snippet,contentDetails",
        "maxResults": 50,
        "playlistId": PLAYLIST_ID, 
        "pageToken" : "<the page token string>" //Error is in this line
    }).then(function(response) {
```