# Angular 7 issue in IE 11

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills

I am working on a Angular 7 project, app is loading fine in Chrome but not in IE. After researching I uncommented polyfills.ts and ran

```
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

but still I am facing same error.

Error from IE:

```
SCRIPT5005: String expected
js (26, 286)
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
polyfills.js (3555, 3)


polyfills.ts
    /**
     * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
     * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
     *
     * This file is divided into 2 sections:
     *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
     *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
     *      file.
     *
     * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
     * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
     * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
     *
     * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
     */
    
    /***************************************************************************************************
     * BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */
    
    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
     import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
     import 'core-js/es6/object';
     import 'core-js/es6/function';
     import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
     import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
     import 'core-js/es6/number';
     import 'core-js/es6/math';
     import 'core-js/es6/string';
     import 'core-js/es6/date';
     import 'core-js/es6/array';
     import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
     import 'core-js/es6/map';
     import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
     import 'core-js/es6/set';
    
    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
    
    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    
    
    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
    // Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
    
    
    /**
     * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
     * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
     * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
     **/
    import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
    
    /**
     * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
     * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
     */
    
     // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
     // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
     // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
    
     /*
     * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
     * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
     */
    // (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
    
    /***************************************************************************************************
     * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
     */
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
    
    
    
    /***************************************************************************************************
     * APPLICATION IMPORTS
     */
```

Comment: It could be an IE11 compatability mode issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280002/988163

Comment: Added  this tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> also but still no luck.